# ListView overlaid by Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have the problem that my `Toolbar` overlaid my ListView.

short info: I've implemented a Navigation Drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/project_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/listview_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/emptyProjects"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listviewNoContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Sie haben zur Zeit keine Aufgaben"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#a4a5ae" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/examplesbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@color/kevox"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Beispiele anfordern"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Can someone tell my what I do wrong?
Maybe it's the position in the XML? 
Or do I choosed the wrong style?

I followed this Guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: add layout below in toolbar in listview

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: instead of using relative layout use linear layout with vertical orintation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line  `android:layout_below="@+id/container"` I have add this .. check this

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/project_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/listview_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/listview_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/emptyProjects"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/listviewNoContent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Sie haben zur Zeit keine Aufgaben"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#a4a5ae" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/examplesbutton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/boxcolor"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Beispiele anfordern"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The `navList` is the ListView for the Navigation Drawer

Comment: I will be very thankful if you can vote up my question too! :)